# Need to calculate discount amount with precision

Tags: trigger, process-builder

I have a requirement, where in a discoiunt % and discount amount is set for the List price.

Whenever , Sales rep fills in discount number, discount % is calculated , whenever sales rep fills in discount %, discount number is calculated.
I have built process builder for this functionality. The functionality is working properly, bt there is one problem , I need solution on.

Lets say , List price for a product is 335 , so if discount amount is 73 , it will calculate 21.79% as discount.

However , when discount % is 21.79 , its showing 73 as discount amount , whereas the actual discount amount should be 72.9965 . I dont want it to show 73 , It should show 72.99

I know its a very small difference, bt since the company gets involved in bulk order sale, the amount lost becomes huge.

Can anybody advise, how can I achieve this precision.

Answer (score 1):

The value is internally stored with as many digits of precision as possible; even though the percentage may display as 73%, it really is stored as the correct value. Should you perform any arithmetic with the percentage, the actual result should also come out to be correct. In fact, you should make sure that you do round the value to some level of precision in the Process Builder using a formula (perhaps to 2 decimal places) so that the displayed value will match the calculated value. You should also change the display format of the field to show 2 decimal places in order to prevent rounding while the value is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using Number field with two decimal places. Hope it will help you.

[image]